# iOS 7 status bar overlap the text in view

Tags: iphone, ios

iOS 7 status bar overlap the view. The text shows in the header of the screen. I want to show the screen with out the text in header called "Carrier, 4:49, and Battery"

How to handle this in iOS 6 and iOS 7 ?
[image]

Comment: change your view frame..

Comment: Just set the status bar to hidden?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18980925/1545180 use this you will get the solution.

Comment: I think this link may be useful for you: http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/09/developers-guide-to-the-ios-7-status-bar/

Answer (score 1):

You could hide it, I think that would look better in your case.

In your app plist add this

View controller-based status bar appearance, and set to NO

Comment: add this as well Status bar is initially hidden = YES

Answer (score 1):

I think that it can help you:

```
 if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)]) {
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you are not the only one with this problem,
while on iOS before 7 the {0, 0} point was just below the status bar it is now at the top of the screen my advice is to add +20.0f to every y coordinate if in iOS 7

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
   // normal comportment
} else {
   // add 20.0f offset
   // you might also want to add a UIImageView subview to go behind the status bar (20pt of height, full width)
}
```

you might do it in view didLoad, for my part I calculate my elements position in static variables initialized in the +(void)initialize class method of my view controllers

if in -(void)viewDidLoad something like

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
   // normal comportment
} else {

   for (UIView *v in self.view.subviews) {
     CGRect oldFrame = v.frame;
     v.frame = CGRectMake(oldFrame.origin.x, oldFrame.origin.y + 20.0f, oldFrame.size.width, oldFrame.size.height);
   }

   // you might also want to add a UIImageView subview to go behind the status bar (20pt of height, full width)
}
```

Comment: Where we have to write this condition ?

Comment: What we can write to add offset 20 PX ?

Comment: Thanks Jerome, code works for me, but status bar shows in white color, can we change color of status bar ?

Comment: I didn't manage to change it, have you read my little comment in the source code "// you might also want to add a UIImageView subview to go behind the status bar (20pt of height, full width)"

Comment: another thing you can do is change the backgroundcolor or the "main" view

Answer (score 0):

Its not a iOS 7 problem. Because status bar is transparent in iOS7. So you need to handle it manually.So please use right image here.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you [How to fix iOS 7 Status bar overlapping issue and status bar style](http://just-works.blogspot.in/2013/11/how-to-fix-ios-7-status-bar-overlapping_1350.html)

which worked for me.