# UIView display issue in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, view, ios7

I already make the app for ios 6 using xib. All the views are shown perfectly same as xib.
But in IOS 7, due to the status Bar the views are moves to up & there is a blank space towards the bottom.

**How can I solve this issue?**

Comment: See this answer it will helps u to fix this issue http://stackoverflow.com/a/19025547/1545180

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move your views so they appear correctly for iOS7 and use the `iOS6/7 Deltas` setting in interface builder to add the correct amount of delta height so your view appears correctly in iOS6.

[image: iOS 6/7 Deltas]

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19025547/1545180

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. But I can able to solve this. Can you give some example or reference?

Comment: See edit. You make your view for iOS 7, and set a delta to fix it for iOS 6.

Comment: Yes it is good, but I also set the frame programatically. So, how can I set the delta for that also?

Comment: For the views you set programmatically, you will have to calculate yourself according to OS version.

Answer (score 3):

For IOS7 you have leave status bar height from top which was by default in IOS6.

```
float SystemVersion=[[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];

if(SystemVersion<7.0f)
{
    //Currently your app is running in IOS6 or older version. So you need not to do anything.  
}
else
{
    // Currently your app is running in IOS7. Do the following.

    CGRect TempRect;
    for(UIView *sub in [[self view] subviews])
    {
        TempRect=[sub frame];
        TempRect.origin.y+=20.0f; //Height of status bar
        [sub setFrame:TempRect];
    }
}
```

Comment: But then the area below the status bar will be black and it will appear incorrectly. He would then have to specify in each view controller that status bar style should be light content. Too much work, and goes against iOS7 design guidelines.

Comment: check my updated answer. Here I am moving down all the view by 20.0f for IOS7.

Comment: He can do this with no hassle in interface builder. The code is not necessary.

Comment: Can We Move Window Itself To 20px Down?

Comment: @LeoNatan: How To Achieve With Xib?

Answer (score 2):

**Steps to Fix the status bar issue:**

1. Change the "**view as**" option to "**IOS 7 and later**" and **uncheck the use auto layout** option from file inspector.
2. Go to size inspector and **increase 20 pixel of origin  y** value to **all controls added in the selected xib**.
3. And increase the **delta value of y to -20** for **all the controls** added in the selected xib.

And run in both IOS 6 and IOS 7 issues should be fixed. (**Make sure the y origin and delta values are perfectly handled as i mentioned.)**

For clear information See my answer in this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/19025547/1545180

For your reference

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can easily set the UIView content properly in ios7 and ios6 by using ios6/7 delta shows on the size inspector by changing the values in delta x,delta y,delta width,delta height.firstly set your values for ios7 in x,y,width,height and then check out and then set deltas for ios6 by subtracting and adding numbers.I also do like that and it is so easy ,you can get help from me ant time..thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom `UINavigationController` try setting the `translucent` property of the `navigationBar` to `NO` like:

```
navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

This worked for me