# iOS7 XIB issue. blank space at top and bottom

Tags: ios, image, ios7, xib, autolayout

I am having a view on which I am setting an ImageView. Auto layout is checked. It looks good in the preview, but when app actually runs on the simulator, there is blank space is showing at the top as well as bottom only in the iPHone retina 4 inch simulator. on 3.5 inch it looks fine. Using iOS7 and XCODE 5.

Even though i removed image from view, still there is the same problem.

[image: Blank space at the top and bottom]

What can be reason for this blank space ?

Comment: the reason for the blank space may be that you are not using the Splash screen for 4" Display. Its not an issue of iOS7 its issue for iPhone 5 and 5S with 4" Display.

Comment: This Link may help http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L8HwmRA2IAk

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIView display issue in iOS 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042918/uiview-display-issue-in-ios-7)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think are you Forget to adding splash screen **Default-568h@2x.png** in to you Project please check Property and set required splash-screen **Default-568h@2x.png** (640 × 1136 pixels) and clean project and run again

Comment: Why Add To Spash Screen? Any Idea about It ? Y/N

Comment: @kirtimali I know but i ask about add the image, Why?

Comment: without lunch screen it display blank screen when app lunch so

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32048884/ios-customkeyboard-how-to-set-special-character-in-custom-keyboard/32049081#32049081