# Auto Layout issue in XCode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, autolayout

So I've been working on an XCode Project for a while, it's practically done but there's a problem I didn't realize until it was too late. I'm working without Size Classes but with Auto Layout. I have a background image in the back and some buttons and labels over it. When I was setting the constraints for everything it all seemed to be in its place and I tested it various times in the same device size (iphone 5s) with the simulator. Now I decided to test it with the iPhone 6, and everything is wrong and not in the place I want it to be. **How do I make labels/text fields/buttons keep the same size in ratio to the device?? How could I adapt things proportionally?? Please help.**

Comment: Add an image of what is wrong and an image of what you expect to see. Just telling SO that something is "wrong and not in the place I want it to be" does not help. If you want to proportionally size something horizontally (for instance) set a constraint between the widths where the ratio is the proportion. The same for proportional vertical sizing.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same issue , But after some R&D found useful solution .

Have a look into given link :[Set view controller in ratio for iPhone-6 and 6+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31469940/3024579)

Its very easy process and working for me .

Comment: If still getting any issue then drop comment here .

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for the bad explanations but I've found the way to do it. Here's the video that explained me how use constraints based on proportions and not on pixels. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gl6DibzPYa4
(The first 5 minutes is basically it)