# How can i set Origin of view from interface builder

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I want solve status bar issue with IOS7 in my ipad app. I found solution on [Status bar and navigation bar issue in IOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980925/status)[image]-bar-issue-and-navigation-bar-issue-in-ios7/19025547#19025547  but i am unable to set **origin-y** . How can i set y in interface builder.

Comment: You can't. But you can put a subview onto the view and set the origin of that subview.

Comment: please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980925/status-bar-issue-and-navigation-bar-issue-in-ios7/19025547#19025547
in this origin-y is 20

Comment: No. Only the origin of the subviews are changed. Quote: `Increase the origin - y with 20 pixel (exactly the size of the status bar) for all the controls added in the view controller.`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting iOS 6/7 `delta y` to `-20`

Comment: I can set iOS 6/7 delta y = -20 but i also have to set y that is disable

Comment: oh for that you can free form the nib file and set the containerview's y to 20