# UINavigaionBar doesn't work with translucent in iOS7

Tags: uinavigationbar, ios7

I have seen a lot of posts in this site.

So they said when `translucent` property to `NO` , It's fine in iOS7.

For me , it doesn't work.

Here is my codes.

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setEdgesForExtendedLayout:)]) {
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
    }

    self.nBar.translucent = NO;
```

It still covering statusBar with `NavigationBar` in iOS7.

like this pic.

[image]

How can i do that?

Comment: In the sense status bar overlapping the view. is it?

Comment: i added photo bro. please look.

Comment: Ok you need to handle the alignment of the each controls while migrating your application to IOS 7 please check this  http://stackoverflow.com/a/19025547/1545180

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While migrating to IOS 6 to IOS 7 You need to handle the alignment of the controls which are added in the Xib to resolve the status bar overlapping issue. Xcode provide delta value provision for each controls that will handle the alignment (based on the delta vale and ios version.)

Things to do :
set the "view as" option as - IOS 7 and later

[image]

**And increase the y value as 20 and set delta value for all the controls as -20**

[image]

For more clarification refer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19025547/1545180

Comment: I use custom background Image for my UINavigationBar bro.

Comment: So have any problem still?

Comment: Yes bro. your method is fine , but my custom background is fix with UINavigationBar. So above status Bar position background color is not match with my NavBar.

Comment: You can change the status bar style.