# How to make status bar opaque in iOS7?

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, ios7, uinavigationbar, statusbar

I'm using a navigation controller (with navigation bar and toolbar) in my app. Triggered by tapping the bars slide in and out with a custom animation. Almost everything works fine with iOS7 so far.

The problem I have is the translucency of the status bar:

From what I understand from this question [iOS 7 status bar back to iOS 6 style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294872/ios-7-status-bar-back-to-ios-6-style/18855464#18855464) (especially from jaredsinclair's answer/blogpost) and from this [Status bar issue and navigation bar issue in ios7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980925/status-bar-issue-and-navigation-bar-issue-in-ios7?lq=1)  is that the status bar is just always translucent. To get the iOS6 status bar look and feel they (simply spoken :)) moved the view 20 points downwards.
Sadly that does not help me with my translucency problem. Because the overall look of the app is quite puristic, it just looks so wrong and confusing to the user's eye when the navigationbar is sliding up and it is still visible while sliding  up behind the status bar.

So I tried to simulate the sliding with non-proportional scaling, but it's just not the same. So my next idea would be to somehow make the status bar background opaque. Is this possible? I tried to sandwich some opaque view between status and navigation bar, but I failed.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: +1 for the opaque view sandwiching idea