# iOS 7 button tappability issue in iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, ios6, ios7, statusbar

When I run the app in iOS 6 ,everything works perfectly fine but when I run on iOS 7 the status bar is visible as per the iOS 7 standards. To get back the iOS6 look and feel in iOS 7, I use the following code :

```
    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    frame.origin.y = 20;

    if (self.view.frame.size.height == 1024 ||
        self.view.frame.size.height == 768) //643
    {
        frame.size.height -= 20;
    }

    self.view.frame = frame;
```

Using this code the UI looks fine on iOS 7. But then one more issue comes. I have few UIButtons at the bottom bar of the screen. Using the above code makes these button partially tappable in iOS 7. There is no button tappability problem in iOS6. Has anyone come across such a situation. If yes then please let me know how to resolve this.

Comment: See this you can get ride of the status bar issue http://stackoverflow.com/a/19025547/1545180

Comment: If you feel hard to understand my answer in the above link let me known i will clarify,.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Ganpathy. It was working for iOS7 but not for iOS6... Finally did it this way. Open each xib/storyboard. Tap on File Inspector. Under Interface Builder Document select Opens in xcode 4.6 . Then add Status bar is initially hidden as YES in your app`s info.plist

Answer (score 0):

If you want exact look like iOS 6 than you have to make build from `MAC OS 10.8... OR xCode 4.6...`.

If you working on latest `MAC OX 10.9... OR xCode 4.5` than you will get the lots of design issue in iOS7 Device..