# status bar showing in iOS 7.0

Tags: ios

```
  if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {

        [application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

        self.window.clipsToBounds =YES;

        self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(0,20,self.window.frame.size.width,self.window.frame.size.height-20);
    }
```

i am using this  code it will  adjust the status bar but when i present any view controller it will give problem.

Comment: follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980925/status-bar-issue-and-navigation-bar-issue-in-ios7

Comment: plz follow above link for solution.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 7 the status bar is transparent and it is not a part of the window hope you understand this.

Comment: it will working fine. but when i prensent a view controller over another view controller my top bar.png is hidden under the status bar. Thats the problem.???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980925/status-bar-issue-and-navigation-bar-issue-in-ios7


You should follow this link it may help you there are steps to manage this thing

Answer (score 0):

in your view controller if it embedded in UINavigationController use this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    //add this 2 lines:
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: i adding these two lines but still not working.. it shows white space below status bar.

Comment: read the solution in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980925/status-bar-issue-and-navigation-bar-issue-in-ios7?lq=1