# iOS7 Hide Navigation Bar Offset Issue

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, ios7, uinavigationbar

I have a view controller that upon pressing a button, hides the navigation bar by using

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:true animated:YES];
```

and show another view in its place that I unhide.

[image: prior to hiding]

I hide the navigation bar because it looks like I can't put any views on top of it without unhiding it.

[image: after hiding and putting view in front]

Anyways, I noticed all the subviews got shifted upwards after hiding the navigation bar, so I did the following for all my subviews

```
// shift subviews down b/c of offset
CGRect categorizationSearchBarFrame = _categorizationSearchBar.frame;
categorizationSearchBarFrame.origin.y += IOS_7_OFFSET;
_categorizationSearchBar.frame = categorizationSearchBarFrame;

CGRect collectionViewFrame = _collectionView.frame;
collectionViewFrame.origin.y += IOS_7_OFFSET;
_collectionView.frame = collectionViewFrame;
```

I remembered to unhide the navigation bar and storing the "navigation hidden state" when navigating to other view controllers, so I can recreate the state coming back.

However, when I do come back and detects the "hidden state" in

`viewWillAppear`

and proceed to do that same unhide, offset procedure, the subviews still appear to be shifted upwards.

[image: subviews still seems to be shifted upwards even after running code to shift them down]

Only when I put the restoration code in

`viewDidAppear`

does the state get restored correctly.  But since the view already appeared on screen, there's an annoying glitch that happens as a result.  Does the view have to be shown before doing any offset changes?  Would love someone's input on this.  Thank you.

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/19025547/1545180 you can get ride out of the status bar issue.

Comment: @Ganapathy thanks, but I suspected that doesn't solve the navigation bar issue, but rather status bar.  I tried it but unfortunately it didn't seem to work.

Comment: have you un-commented all the line you have returned regarding the status bar issue while trying to fix with delta value us i mentioned. If not it will give the side effects thats y.