# iOS 7 status bar issue with auto layout

Tags: iphone, ios7, statusbar

My apps contains various xibs, I am using Auto Layout to adjust view to support various devices. The problem is on iOS6 my views leaving 20 pixel distance for status bar, since this has changed in iOS7. I searched on net and came across approach that by adjusting delta we can overcome this issue, but this will not work when we use Auto Layout, and I do not want to change it through code so is there way to handle this issue using interface builder also?

Update:
I am not using Storyboard either.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please take a look http://stackoverflow.com/a/19025547/1545180

Comment: Thanks @Ganapathy, but as I mentioned I am using Auto layout this solution will not work. We will not get delta in IB.

Comment: @NuzhatZari, Did you got any solution for this because I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: As suggested I am adding view on each xib and its constraint I am modifying runtime, and all other subviews constraint I am providing w.r.t to this view.If you get some better solution do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's not really possible without a storyboard.
I'd like to find a workaround but...

Check this official post about that very issue:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1797/_index.html

Answer (score -1):

you can always try setting frames for your view programatically, but strongly recommend to switch of your auto layout. as you knw dat 20 px status bar is embedded in ios 7, so you can always calcluate the frame.  other then dat derz also another way instead of autolayout use constraints.

Comment: I am using Auto layout because I am supporting different form factor, and I do not want to adjust frame programmatically.