# iOS 7 status bar back to iOS 6 style's issue

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I use the way here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18387241/2717264

everything ok, but when I presentViewController a UIImagePickerController, the window show like this:

[image]

than, I custom a pickerController subclass from UIImagePickerController, in the pickerController viewDidLoad add this code:

```
#define AppDelegate ((WeikeAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate])

AppDelegate.window.clipsToBounds = NO;
AppDelegate.window.frame =  CGRectMake(0, 0, AppDelegate.window.frame.size.width, AppDelegate.window.frame.size.height + 20);
AppDelegate.window.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, AppDelegate.window.frame.size.width, AppDelegate.window.frame.size.height);
```

it work fine, but when pickerController dismiss, window display incorrect again:

[image]

I try to solve it by adding this code in the viewWillDisappear of pickerController, but useless, any idea?

```
AppDelegate.window.clipsToBounds = YES;
AppDelegate.window.frame =  CGRectMake(0, 20, AppDelegate.window.frame.size.width, AppDelegate.window.frame.size.height -20);
AppDelegate.window.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 20, AppDelegate.window.frame.size.width, AppDelegate.window.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19025547/1545180 use this.

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/

Comment: my viewControllers design by programming， any way without stroyboard? @Ganapathy

Comment: So you need to handle programmatically by adding 20pxl to all your controller if the device version is > IOS 7.0

Comment: @Ganapathy , I have do it, and it work fine,  but when I presentViewController a UIImagePickerController, just like what I ask this question.

Comment: @NANNAV I have try, it didnot work, and I have downloaded your example and added a button to presentViewController a UIImagePickerController, then I see it also have the problem, the window show just like the screenshot I upload here the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by doing lots of test, I set a 640*128(pixels) image as the background of the navigationbar, **this is the image(40 pixels height black block as the statuebar and 88 pixels height block as the navigationbar**):

[image]

then it display Correct in case of UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera，if u presentViewController the UIImagePickerController in the case of UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary(I think this will be also Suitable for presentViewController the other view controller with a navigationbar, but I haven't do a test yet), u should subclass from UIImagePickerController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault];
}


- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
}
```

Prerequisites：

have this code in the your first view controller:

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    /*navigation config*/
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image-navigation-bk"]
                                                  forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)])
    {
        [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Xcode 5 has iOS 6/7 Deltas which is specifically made to resolve this issue. In the storyboard, I moved my views 20 pixels down to look right on iOS 7 and in order to make it iOS 6 compatible, I changed Delta y to -20.

[image]

Since my storyboard is not using auto-layout, in order to resize the height of views properly on iOS 6 I had to set Delta height as well as Delta Y.

Comment: my viewControllers design by programming， any way without stroyboard?

Comment: if iOS 7 should start with y-coordinate is 20 or else 0.