# Small space at the bottom of the device in ios7

Tags: ios7, statusbar

We are developing an application working on both ios6 and ios7

My problem is that, If I check my application in device there is a small white space equal to the size of the status bar at the bottom of the screen.

If I put a dummy status bar at the top of the screen it will make problem in ios6, Help me if you have any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the common status bar issue while migrating application from IOS 6 to IOS 7 use this to get ride of the issue:

For more reference

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19025547/1545180

You need to set the delta value for all the controls followed by increasing the origin x to 20pix for all the controls.

Step 1: Increase origin y to 20 pixel (for all the controls in the .xib)
step 2 . And set delta y to - 20 for all the controls in Xib.
Step 3 . Finally change the view as version in interface builder.

**If your adding the controls programmatically you need to handle the frames** (increase the y position based on the version ) of the added controls like this

```
 if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0f)
    {
        [_programmaticallyAddedControl setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 36, 176, 428)];
    }
    else
    {
        [_programmaticallyAddedControl setFrame:CGRectMake:CGRectMake(20, 56, 176, 428)];
    }
```

Comment: I draw controls in the viewcontroller based on the data from the server.so How to programmatically draw them in the view controller after viewDidLoad

Comment: So you are adding controls programmatically?