# Status Bar in IOS 7

Tags: ios6, ios7, statusbar, uistatusbar

So it's well known that the UIViewController view goes under the status bar. My GUI is developed entirely programmatically, so none of the posts that I found on SO solved the problem for me. In particular,

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
     self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

does nothing whatsoever!

Question: is there a setting or a command to make my GUI in IOS 7 work just like it did in IOS 6: the UIViewController view goes right under the status bar (20px down from the top of the screen).

Many thanks in advance,

Sam

Comment: Happened to see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19025547/1545180?

Comment: If you are adding the controls programmatically you need to handle the frame based on the IOS version. PLease see this too http://stackoverflow.com/a/20093515/1545180.

Comment: Have you fixed that issues?

Comment: No, I have not been able to figure it out. Perhaps I should resize the UIWindow? I simply want the window to fit underneath the status bar. I'm willing to try any suggestion.

Comment: happened to check those link? update your question with once screen shot that help us to understand the issue easily.