# How to make .xib files compatible to both iOS7, iOS6 and earlier

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7

I am using .xib files in my app and I am using xcode5.

If I run my app in iOS6 and earlier, the alignments are missing.

Any one know about this issue?
Do we have to create separate .xib files for iOS7 and iOS6?

EDIT: I turned off Autolayout but under iOS6, the views are still going down by 20 pixels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in iOS7, the app windows starts from y=0px (in iOS6-, it begins at y=20px).

The quickest and easiest way to handle this, (*and since you're already using Xcode5*), is to switch off Autolayout and utilize the **iOS6/7 Delta** values for every view.

Basically:

- Select every `viewController`'s main `view` and uncheck "`Use Autolayout`"
- Select every `subView` (`UIButton`, `UILabel` etc), go to the frame setting section

  1. Increase their Y frame values by 20

     - *but it seems **you**, @SudhakarTharigoppula, don't need to do this step.

       ...just do the next step*
  2. Enter a value of -20 for **ΔY**

This will start your app by leaving 20px in iOS7 but back in iOS6, the **ΔY** of -20px will compensate for the extra 20px you had given to every `subView`.

see: [Status bar and navigation bar issue in IOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980925/status-bar-and-navigation-bar-issue-in-ios7)

Comment: This is what I was looking for. 
Setting the ΔY appropriately did the trick for me. +1.

Answer (score 4):

If you haven't done so already, turn off AutoLayout in your xib files.  Autolayout only came in with iOS 6 and newer iOS versions.

Also, you can preview what XIB files look like between iOS 6 and iOS 7 via a popup menu in the File Inspector:

[image: File Inspector in Interface Builder]