# Why does my app look like this in the multitasking drawer?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

In my AppDelegate I've customized the colors of the UINavigationBar, but when I double tap the home button to open the multitasking drawer, my app preview looks like this:

[image]

When in reality its supposed to look like this:

[image]

(Just ignore the different content in app.)

This is the code I use for changeing colors and fonts:

```
// set navigation bar colors
UINavigationBar *navigationBar = [UINavigationBar appearance];
navigationBar.barTintColor = redColor;
navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{
                                      NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor],
                                      NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"SOLIDARITET" size:26.0]
                                      };
```

Comment: @JohnRiselvato I'm using Storyboard, and the MainStoryboard says it's white.

Comment: wait... your porting from before ios 7 aren't you?

Comment: Correct @JohnRiselvato, guess there's something I've missed during the version upgrade?

Comment: Yeah, you are using iOS 7 properties on iOS 6 UI elements. As you can see you're getting a gradient on your UINavigationBar, that gradient is an iOS 6 property. I'm unsure how you solve this but I would check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20776131/how-to-make-xib-files-compatible-to-both-ios7-ios6-and-earlier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. I selected my Storyboard file, and set the background color in the Attributes Inspector **from** currentColor to whiteColor.