# view goes beneath of navigation bar and status bar

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios7

In my app i'm using navigation controller in the mainwindow...after that i added iAdd in to the navigation controller (using subclassing of navigation controller).so my problem is when iAdd is comes to the view then view goes beneath of navigation bar and status bar so i'm getting it's frame like this (0,0,320,450) ..... need help to solve this problem ....
i have used this code but it's not working

```
self.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;   // iOS 7 specific
```

here "self" is my subclassed navigation controller class object...because all codes for iAdd is managed in the subclassed navigation controller class

Comment: here is the same thread, you can go though it may help you out.....
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980925/status-bar-and-navigation-bar-issue-in-ios7

Comment: thanks for u r commets kamarshad... i tried that links but didn't get solution for my situation....