# StatusBar background color in iOS7

Tags: ios7, uistatusbar, ios7.1, ios7-statusbar

Im working on a app compatible from ios6 onwards. in iOS 7 status bar is overlapping views and navigationbar. i want status bar in iOS 6 style. like it should appear above all UI objects, views,Viewcontroller and navigation controller. how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

For fixing the overlapping issue just try this link [Status bar and navigation bar issue in IOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980925/status-bar-and-navigation-bar-issue-in-ios7)

and for using status bar style similar to ios 6 this link may help you [Change StatusBar style](http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/StatusBar.html)

In your app delegate's applicationDidFinishLaunching method:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
```

Set UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent/UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque for getting status bar similar to iOS6.

Hope this may help you

Answer (score 1):

**I am late for this Answer**, but i just want to share what i did, which is basically
the easiest solution

**First of all->** Go to your `info.plist` File and add `Status Bar Style->Transparent Black Style(Alpha of 0.5)`

**Now ,here it Goes:-**

Add this code in your AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
     //Whatever your code goes here
  if(kDeviceiPad){

     //adding status bar for IOS7 ipad
         if (IS_IOS7) {
              UIView *addStatusBar = [[UIView alloc] init];
              addStatusBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 20);
              addStatusBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1]; //change this to match your navigation bar
              [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:addStatusBar];
                    }
                }
    else{

         //adding status bar for IOS7 iphone
        if (IS_IOS7) {
            UIView *addStatusBar = [[UIView alloc] init];
            addStatusBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 20);
            addStatusBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1]; //You can give your own color pattern
            [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:addStatusBar];
        }

    return YES;
   }
```