# iOS 7 Status Bar Collides With NavigationBar using ViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, ios7-statusbar

I am a beginner with iOS development. Currently I have migrating a ios5 code to the ios7.

Getting the following overlap issue in my code : http://s17.postimg.org/90m7mx5lb/collide.png

I have updated the app delegate with the following code :

```
self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(0,20,self.window.frame.size.width,self.window.frame.size.height-20);
```

The interface etc, is generated directly via ViewController code and not using Interface Builder or StoryBuilder.

Please advice..

**UPDATE:**

Using the following in all viewcontroller

`UIImage *stretchImage=[UIImage imageNamed:kNavigationBg];
    stretchImage=[stretchImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:1 topCapHeight:0];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:stretchImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];`

Comment: May [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980925/status-bar-and-navigation-bar-issue-in-ios7) can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Select each ViewController in your Storyboard and, tick both options "Under top bars" , "Under bottm bars"

[image]

Programmatically ,

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Comment: there is no story board.. entire code is done via viewcontroller.m

Comment: then use `edgesForExtendedLayout` , `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars`

Comment: sorry but where do i add this in appdelegate or individual viewcontroller. I am very new to ios.. thanks

Comment: In each VeiwController's viewDidLoad

Comment: added the view controller code in the main question.. will this help??

Answer (score 0):

Set View controller-based status bar appearance to NO in ur plist.

Comment: I have a VideoPlayer, when I set view controller-based status bar to NO, and return to the app. The sizing becomes perfect. please advice.

Comment: after returning from mediaplayer the height of navbar updates as desired

Comment: added the view controller code in the main question.. will this help??

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```
if(IS_IOS7)
{
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```

Comment: Try UIRectEdgeBottom and also if your navigation bar is opaque try     [self setExtendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars:YES]

Comment: In appdelegate try add [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque]; with the above code unchanged

Comment: added the view controller code in the main question.. will this help??